# Docker for windows failing to start

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-10, hyper-v

I've just upgraded to the Windows 10 Pro creators update | 1703 | OS Build: 15063.138.

When docker tries to start I get the following error:

```
Unable to create: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 137
at Get-NetAdapter<End>, <No file>: line 181
at New-Switch, <No file>: line 137
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 381
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
```

Now I've tried all the usual troubleshooting methods to try to fix it but have had no luck i.e. uninstall docker reninstall, turn off hyper-V then turn it back on again.

I've even tried running the following commands using Powershell in  `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources`

```
.\MobyLinux.ps1 -Destroy
.\MobyLinux.ps1 -Create
```

The create task throws the following error:

```
? : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\MobyLinux.ps1:137 char:37
+ ...  Get-NetAdapter | ? { $_.Name.StartsWith("vEthernet ($SwitchName)") }
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Where-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you check the output of `Get-NetAdapter`? (unfiltered). I don't know any case where `$_.Name` could be `$null`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same what i did to fix it was.

1. Uninstall Docker and Remove Hyper-V from the control panel. Go into
   device manager -> network adapters.
2. Right click and uninstall any that are not your actual physical network card
3. Reboot and Turn Hyper-V back on and reinstall Docker (Or just install Docker as it turns on Hyper-V for you).